# Java swing timer not working in Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, timer

i am trying to build a JFrame with a swing Timer in a border layout that contains 2 JPanels, both having Timer that suppose to work together, but only one of them work. The timer in the toolbar panel doesnt work.

```
public class trygame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JPanel _toolbar = new JPanel(); 
private Play game;
private Timer _timer;
private int _count = 0;

public trygame(Level lvl) {
    super("Elemental Brick Breaker");
    _timer = new Timer(1000,this);
    _timer.start();
    File jarPath=new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    String levelsPath=jarPath.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();    
    String path = levelsPath + "\\src\\pics\\gameIcon.png";
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path);
    this.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton returnButton = new JButton("Return");
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    Dimension d = new Dimension(150,50);
    returnButton.setPreferredSize(d);
    returnButton.setMinimumSize(d);
    _toolbar.add(returnButton,c);
    _toolbar.setBackground(Color.black);
    add(_toolbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    game  = new Play(lvl.getBoard());
    add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(615,750);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    game.setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == _timer) {
        _count++;
        JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("     Timer: " + Integer.toString(_count));
        int Destroyed = game.getDestroyed();
        JLabel jlabel2 = new JLabel("    Destroyed: " + Integer.toString(Destroyed));
        jlabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana",1,20));
        jlabel2.setFont(new Font("Verdana",1,20));
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(150,50);
        jlabel.setPreferredSize(d);
        jlabel2.setMinimumSize(d);
        _toolbar.add(jlabel,c);
        _toolbar.add(jlabel2,c);
        _toolbar.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you create new labels at every move, rather play around withthe existing labels. In any event, you never remove the old labels, not leaving room for your new labels to show.

Comment: i added _toolbar.remove for the labels at the start of the actionPreformed method and it just displays them, removing them, and not adding them back

Comment: You need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on a container whose had its child components added or removed